# If and else with OnCheckedChangeListener android

Tags: android

I am having a hard time understanding how could I rewrite this code using EditText and if and else, so when one or multiple check box is checked it writes in edit text field not as notification. Which parts should I change. Can someone help?

```js
      public class CheckBoxCheckedDemo extends Activity
    {
        CheckBox chkBoxAndroid;
        CheckBox chkBoxIPhone;
        CheckBox chkBoxBlackBerry;
     
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
     
            initialUISetup();
        }
     
         public void initialUISetup() {
                chkBoxAndroid = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBoxAndroid);
                chkBoxIPhone = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBoxIPhone);
                chkBoxBlackBerry = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBoxBlackBerry);
     
                chkBoxAndroid.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new myCheckBoxChnageClicker());
                chkBoxIPhone.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new myCheckBoxChnageClicker());
                chkBoxBlackBerry.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new myCheckBoxChnageClicker());
         }
     
         class myCheckBoxChnageClicker implements CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener
         {
     
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
             // Toast.makeText(CheckBoxCheckedDemo.this, &quot;Checked =&gt; &quot;+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     
              if(isChecked) {
                    if(buttonView==chkBoxAndroid) {
                    showTextNotification("Android");
                }
     
                if(buttonView==chkBoxIPhone) {
                    showTextNotification("iPhone");
                }
     
                if(buttonView==chkBoxBlackBerry) {
                    showTextNotification("BlackBerry");
                }
              }
            }
         }
     
         public void showTextNotification(String msgToDisplay) {
                Toast.makeText(this, msgToDisplay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class myCheckBoxChnageClicker implements CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener

     {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // Toast.makeText(CheckBoxCheckedDemo.this, &quot;Checked =&gt; &quot;+isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          if(chkBoxAndroid.isChecked() || chkBoxIPhone.isChecked() || chkBoxBlackBerry.isChecked())
          {
               edittext.setText("not as notification");
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it work if I want to import checkbox id as static?

Comment: What you mean? explain more @StarterAndroid

Comment: If i put this `import static todo.starter.com.phoneapp.R.id.chkBoxAndroid;` before class instead of defining checkbox in class `CheckBox chkBoxAndroid;`.

Comment: Then you should use `CheckBox chkBoxAndroid = (CheckBox) findViewById(chkBoxAndroid);`. but don't do that @StarterAndroid

Comment: Ok, just for educational purposes - why in this part  `if(chkBoxAndroid.isChecked() || chkBoxIPhone.isChecked() || chkBoxBlackBerry.isChecked())` it cannot resolve method `isChecked()` if I import checkbox as static. I won't do it then but I am really curious.

Comment: you can't because that imported thing is a resource int not a `CheckBox`. btw if this answer helps you accept it as a right answer @StarterAndroid